# Unit Test doesn't work on new Target/Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I create a project including the Unit/UI test by default. After some time as my project becomes bigger, I put a new target, new scheme, with the same code base only things that are different are some Assets/colors and some string variables. Both targets have the same bundle ID but different .plist. I have about 100 test cases written.

Let's say I have:
Target Alpha
Target Beta

The issue is when I run Test's on Alpha target every test works and everything is ok, but when I switch to target Beta and run one or all tests I got two errors and I can not figure what is the issue:

Error code is:

*

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fdvpapcwvwwtepdkbtegmjmvtavl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app':
1) Target 'Alpha' has create directory command with output '/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fdvpapcwvwwtepdkbtegmjmvtavl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app'
2) Target 'Beta' has create directory command with output '/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fdvpapcwvwwtepdkbtegmjmvtavl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app'
Multiple commands produce '/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fdvpapcwvwwtepdkbtegmjmvtavl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName':
1) Target 'Alpha' has link command with output '/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fdvpapcwvwwtepdkbtegmjmvtavl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName'
2) Target 'Beta' has link command with output '/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-fdvpapcwvwwtepdkbtegmjmvtavl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.app/AppName'
```

- 